# Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox75c537762edc4d29becf4de26ec1738b.mailgun.org/messages.mime` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: laravel-5, heroku

Estoy implementando Mailgun en Laravel. hice toda la configuración y desde localhost me funciona perfecto, pero cuando hago deploy en Heroku me sale el siguiente error:

> Client error: `POST
>   https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox75c537762edc4d29becf4de26ec1738b.mailgun.org/messages.mime`
>   resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response: { "message": "Sandbox
>   subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or
>   add the address to authoriz (truncated...)

Estoy usando mi propio dominio, no se que estará fallando, pero en localhost los correos se envían sin problema.

**archivo .env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@email.Mydomain.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=1567---ca----b3f74f23fe
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=email.Mydomain.co
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-03be65a7c90-----f51d---83e4
```

**Services**

```
    'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

Comment: Por alguna razón que desconozco toma este dominio :/sandbox75c537762edc4d29becf4de26ec1738b.mailgun.org y no el mio

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer es un problema que no actualiza los cambios realizados en el archivo .env --> investigaré más sobre este tema.

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera por si alguien tiene el mismo problema:

Reemplacé las lineas del archivo services.php:

**estaban originalmente así:**

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

**las reemplacé por:**

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => ('email.Mydomain.co'),
    'secret' => ('key-03be65a7c90-----f51d---83e4'),
],
```

No se por qué, pero según la documentación es como dicen las minas originales, sin embargo, al reemplazarlas funciona.

Comment: Para actualizar los cambios debes usar: php artisan config:cache